# Configure ColdFusion site on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, coldfusion

I have been asked to migrate a ColdFusion site that is running on Windows Server 2003 to a new server, which is running Windows Server 2008 R2, 64bit.  I am a .Net developer and know my way around Windows and IIS fairly well.  Though, I have never done anything with ColdFusion.  I ran this command: `<cfdump var="#SERVER#" />`  and received the output below. The 2008R2 server is vanilla.  Can someone help me by generally telling me what I need to do to get the site running?  Thanks for any advise given.

```
APPSERVER JRun4  
EXPIRATION {ts '2011-07-01 09:07:52'}  
INSTALLKIT Native Windows  
PRODUCTLEVEL Standard  
PRODUCTNAME ColdFusion Server  
PRODUCTVERSION 7,0,2,142559  
ROOTDIR D:\CFusionMX7  

ADDITIONALINFORMATION [empty string] 
ARCH x86  
BUILDNUMBER [empty string] 
NAME Windows 2003 
VERSION 5.2
```

Comment: Since this is about server configuration, I suggest that [sf] would be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ColdFusion 9 will install much easier on Windows Server 2008. Also it will support the 64-bit mode that you are running in.  You could also run the 32-bit version which may be required if you are running any cfx extensions that don't support 64-bit.

Here's some good info from [Diary of a Grunt](http://www.jasonholden.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/8/7/Coldfusion-8-and-9-on-Windows-Server-2003-Server-2008-Vista-and-Windows-7-x86-and-x64).

Answer (score 2):

Well... you would need to do is install ColdFusion on the new server. Since the site is running version 7 currently you may want to stick with that.  The current production release is 9.01.  You may want to test the site against current version and if all is well upgrade to that.

From there you would have to configure ColdFusion server.  Get any datasources configured and secure the server. These are just a few of the things you will need to do.  This is not indicative of ColdFusion, but a necessary process any time you are moving a site from server to server.

If you have never done it before I would suggest getting help from someone who has.  While it can be fairly easy to do there may be little nuances that a novice may miss.

--Dave

Comment: I realize I am simplifying this, but generally speaking is it just a matter of installing ColdFusion, installing any necessary IIS 7.5 components, perhaps some IIS configuration, creating the IIS site and pointing the the directory to where CF files are saved?  Are you aware of a blog post somewhere that may describe this type of adventure?  I am thinking it cannot be too bad, but since I have never configured a CF site, I wanted to get thoughts here.  I do know Windows and IIS well....so I have that going for me.

Answer (score 2):

A few other things to keep in mind.  Depending on how complex the site is you will need to move the CustomTags and any CFC's in use from the old server to the new server and in some cases these will by in the CFusion directory not in inetpub.

I would echo Dave's comments in that if you haven't done this before I would recommend getting some help from someone who is familiar with ColdFusion.

If you have any other specific questions ask away...

Comment: So I dont run into any compatibility issues, would you recommend installing the version currently running, version 7?  However, besides running in Windows Server 2008 the other difference would be that it will be running on a 64bit machine.  Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think you will have any 64 bit issues, obviously I haven't seen the code and don't know exactly what is under the hood, but generally I have not run into any issues except when the code has been pretty exotic.

As for upgrading from CF7 to CF8 or 9, I would recommend using a test environment before going production.  Personally I would want to go CF9 just to be current plus have the new features available to me.  If your goal is just to get the site running, staying CF7 would be the safe way to go to take variables out of the transition.

Comment: Can have bitness issues if you choose to install the 64-bit version of CF and have older CFX extensions that won't support it.  Need to check if you're current setup has CFX extensions.